# Does EF Core context hold all database values during runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am not able to find answer to my question, when I am debugging my .NET 5 console app and I take a look inside the context (EF Core) I can see that it holds all database tables, when I expand such table (list of entities) I can start to scroll over that list.
One of my table holds around 15 000 records, another one holds around 30 000 records... does it mean that this data is available all the time during runtime? Or is it populated while I am scrolling down the list during debugging?

Comment: Enumerating a db set; eg `db.Set<T>().GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` will cause an sql statement to be executed. Loading the table contents into memory, because you asked for them. Enumerating `db.Set<T>().Local` will show you what's in memory without changing the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because my account is blocked to post new questions and this particular question could be answered by reading the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand the concept of EF (Entity Framework) as an O/RM (Object Relational Mapper). EF enables .NET developers to work with a database using .NET objects. To answer your question: Database query will only occur if you have your SQL statements executed on the context either with LINQ or raw statements. So the answer is NO, the data will only available to you when you need it of course. The one on the context you see through debugging is actually querying the database as you click on it. Hopefully my answer can diminish your curiosity a little. Cheers.

You may also see more details about EF Core from this source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/